# how do i in ignore/disable/delete a javascript call from parent in child theme?

Tags: themes, javascript, child-theme

I am working on a child theme and I want to disable a JavaScript file from the parent folder instead of deleting it.

I have a `functions.php` file in my child theme folder but don't know how to do it.

In my parent folder I have this file in my js folder: `jquery.tipsy.js`
and I want to ignore it in my child theme. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your functions.php file so we can take a look at it? s_ha_dum is correct.

Answer (score 3):

If the script is [registered](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [enqueued](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) correctly you might be able to [deregister](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) it, but you have posted nowhere enough information for me to really say how.

Parent themes load ***after*** the child so that is another potential issue, depending on how the theme is written.

Comment: Thank you all.this is the line i dont want:
if(!is_admin()){

wp_register_script( 'Tipsy', WP_THEME_URL . '/assets/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js', false, null, true);
  wp_enqueue_script( 'Tipsy' );
global $user_ID; if( $user_ID ) : 
   if( current_user_can('level_10') ) : 
    wp_deregister_script( 'Tipsy' );
   endif; 
  endif; 
  
  wp_register_script( 'SkeletonKey', WP_THEME_URL . '/assets/javascripts/skeleton-key.js', false, null, true);
     wp_enqueue_script( 'SkeletonKey' ); 

    }

Comment: Edit you answer to include the code, please. Code formatting in comments is nearly non-existent, making long chunk unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried commenting those lines out?

```
//function this script () blahblah .js
```